# Finding the probability of an AND event without indication if the events are independent or not.

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm studying an introductory statistics textbook and it gave me this problem:

"A special deck of cards has ten cards. Four are green, three are blue, and three are red. When a card is picked, its color of it is recorded. An experiment consists of first picking a card and then tossing a coin.

b.  Let A be the event that a blue card is picked first, followed by landing a head on the coin toss. Find P(A)"

How would I know if the events are independent in which I would use the formula P(A $\cap$ B) = P(A)P(B) or if they're dependent in which I would be then using P(A $\cap$ B) = P(A)P(B). Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: If the coin is fair, your events are independent. Since the outcome of the toss will have no dependence on the card first picked. However, if you were to chose coins with different probability of landing heads depending on the card picked, your events would have been dependent.

Comment: You are supposed to assume that these events are independent just because it's difficult to imagine how they could not be.  How can the color of the card affect the toss of the coin?  Your point is well-taken, but I assure you that you are expected to assume independence.

Comment: In cases like this, the natural assumption to make is that the events are independent.  It is reasonable to believe that the color of the card that is picked has no bearing on the tossing of the coin.